# Rails - putting elements inside Div from view rendered using helper in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml, render

I have two views that creates functioning modal. Top one is made with helper method

```
.modal-header
  %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
  %h3.modal-title
    = title
.modal-body
  (some necessary code)
```

And after that there is the second file with content of that modal that looks like this:

```
generate_top(title)
(...)
```

Now when Rails generate this as a HTML, content of second view is separately of `<div class="modal-body">` in which it should be. Is there any good way to insert view from second file into that `modal-body` div without moving class declaration from first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after all I couldn't find good answer to my problem, so I took different approach:

Instead of generating modal-header using helper, I modified my modal layout like this:

```
#mainModal{:class => "modal", :tabindex => "-1", :role => "dialog" , "aria-labelledby" => "mainModalLabel", "aria-hidden" => "true"}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} &times;
        %h3.modal-title
          =yield :title if content_for? :title
      .modal-body
        (that necessary code that was mentioned before)
        =yield
```

And now I add title to modals by content_for method:

```
=content_for :title do
  ={Modal title}
```